Gamma times confluent hypergeometric function for large arguments
I need to evaluate the following expression for large $|a|$
$\Gamma(a)U(a, 1, x)$,
where $a$ and $x$ are real and $x\geq0$. For moderate values, I can just use mpmath. However, in the limit of large $|a|$ this becomes numerically very inefficient as (eg for negative a) the Gamma function goes to very small numbers why the confluent hypergeometric function becomes very large. Is there any helpful way to rewrite $U$ that is better suited for that problem?

You’re interested in large $a$, right?

yes, that's correct
